# Error for 'program' in launch.json when debugging visual studio code

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code

I use `visual studio code` and plugin for `C#` version `1.10.0-beta1`.
When I try turn of debug, I get error:

> launch: launch.json must be configured. Change 'program' to the path
>   to the executable file that you would like to debug.

I use `ubuntu 17.04`
My settings:

```
{
    "window.menuBarVisibility": "toggle",
    "csharp.fallbackDebuggerLinuxRuntimeId": "ubuntu.16.10-x64",
    "omnisharp.useMono": true,
}
```

My configuration `launch.json`

```
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/<target-framework>/<project-name.dll>",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "console": "internalConsole"
    }
```

What should I write in: `"program":` ?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have built your program. Then, go to the root directory of your program and find your target-framework and project-name under Debug folder.

For example, you have built a hello world program named console1 and your .netcore version is 1.1.0, you will change "program":

"${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug//"

to "program":

"${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/console1.dll".

And you can start your debugging now if you have installed the dotnet core debugger.